# Looking for Kernel Header file for Macros of INTEL ethernet device related macros for base addresses of registers used in I/O

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian, kernel, driver

where is the header file in Linux headers of addresses macros of PCI register's (address as in Memory IO Mapping of devices) for VendorID, DeviceID,CLASS and BASE addresses MACROs (for IO as ins(address) outb(..address)) for intel e1000e device in Debian Linux

Comment: Also there is a macro `INTEL` where this and other macros are which header file?

Answer (score 0):

Each network card is under drivers/net/ethernet/intel.  The E1000 cards, for example, list all the different  model ids in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.17/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000/e1000_hw.h#L409  The vendor ID for Intel is 8086.

PCI addresses are assigned, they are not fixed.

Comment: I have installed linux headers but this file for sure does not exists on my system. What can I do, do I need to include this file in my driver folder after download it before compiling and installation the driver

Comment: I have 5.7.0-kali1-amd64

Comment: What you asked for is all internal to the kernel source.  It's not in the exported headers.

Comment: Are you trying to write your own driver for an existing Intel card?

Comment: that I want to try. How can I include this header file with my driver that I am making and then install and replace my current driver with what I am making

Comment: Download the whole kernel source for 5.7.0 and use what you need.

Comment: and exclude the rest? I just want to compile driver make it module and install and the use it as current ethernet driver

Comment: The linux kernel is monolithic.  If you include any internal header files, then buckle your seat belt.

Comment: do u mean I have to change the driver include my module and then compile and install the entire kernel?

Comment: `What you asked for is all internal to the kernel source.It's not in the exported headers` so including any other header files with my module is not Normal.What drawbacks could arises?I just want 2 learn `where kernel code meets the hardware`. Compiling and installing entire kernel each time I do something will take lots of time.Thats why I am doing it.if kernel is monolithic then it should be but I am just like doing it so I can learn driver/Kernel/and C.Not doing it for production environment.But please do tell why I need to `buckle my seat belt` if I do this in Production too.For info sake

Comment: @stark, actually no, Linux kernel source is **not** monolitic. Many distributions provide a so called kernel-build (whatever name in your distro) package that includes a lot of "private" headers.

Comment: @Alex, Intel provides (at least used to provide) a driver as a separate source ball. You may try to find it somewhere on Intel site. Then you can play with it. And yes, you may build a driver separately from the kernel, just as I said to stark, you need to have additional packages that include necessary headers for your kernel.